# C++ conditional reference to existing or new variable

Tags: c++, reference

I have a function that forwards some large variables via `const` reference like this:

```
void processMore(const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b);

void process(const std::vector<int> &a,
             const std::vector<int> &b) {
  processMore(a, b);
}
```

But I have added an optimisation that modifies them:

```
std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>>
optimise(const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b);
```

I can do it unconditionally like this:

```
void process(const std::vector<int> &a,
             const std::vector<int> &b) {
  auto opt = optimise(a, b);
  processMore(opt.first, opt.second);
}
```

But I want to make it optional. My solution is this:

```
void process(const std::vector<int> &a,
             const std::vector<int> &b,
             bool doOptimisation) {
  auto opt =
      [&]() -> std::pair<const std::vector<int>&,
                         const std::vector<int>&> {
    if (doOptimisation) {
      auto o = optimise(a, b);
      return std::make_pair(o.first, o.second);
    }
    return std::make_pair(a, b);
  }();
  processMore(opt.first, opt.second);
}
```

This seems a bit convoluted. Is there a better way? I want to avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: Red alert! Your lambda returns a pair of dangling references that refer to the dead `o`!

Comment: with "unnecessary" do you mean in case you dont do the optimization or also in case you do it?

Comment: With your current lambda, why not just simply `return optimise(a, b);`?

Comment: @Quentin: Ah yeah I did think about that but was thinking that const references would extend the lifetime. I guess that doesn't extend outside the lambda.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Because `optimise()` returns a pair of values, and I need a pair of references.

Answer (score 3):

The "naive" solution would be something like

```
if (doOptimisation)
{
    auto o = optimise(a, b);
    processMore(o.first, o.second);
}
else
{
    processMore(a, b);
}
```

No extra copying being made.

Comment: Ah yeah I guess I should say that `processMore()` is actually quite a lot of code, so I don't really want to write it all twice.

Comment: @Timmm it is a function that you simply call twice. If it isnt in you real code then the solution is to use a function ;)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I mean, when I said `processMore()` is a lot of code I didn't mean the code *in* `processMore()` is a lot of code - I meant that the code in `process()` is a lot longer than just calling one function. But I guess I can put all *that* code in another function.

Comment: @Timmmm: Exactly, but that's effectively what your lambda is.  This question is sort of moot because it was framed in a way that doesn't match your real code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is this:

```
void process(const std::vector<int> &a,
             const std::vector<int> &b,
             bool doOptimisation) {
  std::optional<std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>>> opt;
  if (doOptimisation) {
    opt = optimise(a, b);
  }
  const auto &aOpt = opt ? opt->first : a;
  const auto &bOpt = opt ? opt->second : b;

  processMore(aOpt, bOpt);
}
```

This is simpler than repeating `processMore()` or moving it into another wrapper function in my actual code (it's hard to convey complicated code in a minimal example).